# or die ("Error") выводит постоянно, что я не так делаю, почему эта ... не пишет в базу

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "fandev");


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $passw = $_POST['passw'];
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $srname = $_POST['srname'];
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$login','$passw','$name','$srname')") or die ("Error");
}
```

?>

Comment: А http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php вам на что? Вангую, что у вас в `user` не совпадает кол-во столбцов с данными, что вы вставляете.

Comment: В базе в таблице если `id` есть, то надо пустую строку в двух кавычках надо оставить в начале.
А так код правильный. Может быть ошибка в подключении к базе, то есть в `$con`

Answer (score 0):

Посмею предположить, что у вас не совпадает количество столбцов в таблице и в запросе, если ваш запрос использует меньше столбцов, чем есть в таблице, то запрос должен иметь такой вид:

```
INSERT INTO users (login, pass, name, srname)VALUES ('$login','$passw','$name','$srname')
```